# Ubuntu 20.10 dbs_work_handler/tick_sched_timer too much power (bluetooth?)

Tags: bluetooth, power-management, asus, amd-ryzen, powertop

Running a Asus G14 (Ryzen 9) Zephyrus and Ubuntu 20.10 and noticed *dbs_work_handler* using 2.5W and *tick_sched_timer* using 1.5W went just idling. Searching around some have mentioned it maybe the bluetooth stack (I'm using a HP Z8000 BT mouse), though turning off BT I save at max 1W, typically 0.35W savings.

Anything else I should check on my these 2 processes are consuming over 4W of power, when system is idling? Or is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

tick_sched_timer is most likely audio playback (pulse).

dbs_work_handler is the ondemand governor, it samples work to be done and modifies the clock speed accordingly.

I do not think there is anything wrong with that, the "extra" power used by ondemand is offset by the gains.

I could be completely wrong and there is something wrong with the ondemand governor!